# PHP Regular expression function conflict

Tags: php, preg-match

I've used  `php 4` function as `spliti()` as well as `php 5` function `preg_match`. It shows output in my localhost (xampp version 1.7.2). But When I upload it to my server it shows nothing at preg_match and return false. I don't know why. Can anybody help me on this?

My function is for getting doctype and char-set of a html page. Functions are given below:

```
function GetContentType($Data) { // data as the html code
     print preg_match('@<meta\s+http-equiv="Content-Type"\s+content="([\w/]+)(;\s+charset=([^\s"]+))?@i', $Data, $matches);
    print var_dump($matches);
    if (isset($matches[3]))
        return $matches[3];
    else
        return "No Character set detected.";
}

function GetDocType($Data) { // Data as the html codes
    print preg_match('/<!DOCTYPE (\w.*)dtd">/is', $Data, $patterns);
    print var_dump($patterns);
    $Data = explode(" ", str_replace('"', "", $patterns[1]));
    $Data = $Data[0] . " " . $Data[3] . " " . $Data[4] . " " . $Data[5];
    return str_replace("//EN", "", $Data);
}
```

Comment: Rather offtopic, but seriously: a doctype scanner that doesn't accept the HTML5 doctype?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation:

```
preg_match() 5.3.6 Returns FALSE if offset is higher than subject length.
```

I assume that will be the issue here...

Comment: Can you tell me how can I solve it? I didn't know the offset and the subject.

Comment: $data is your subject, the offset is where in your subject preg_match should start looking, and by default is set to 0. Basically, this should mean that your $data variable is an empty string.

Comment: can you give me the changed code for this? it will be so much helpful for me.

Comment: Best thing to do is to echo $Data; before you do the preg_match thing. This way you can debug $Data.

Comment: actually I'm totally new in regular expression. So I've no idea what are you saying. As for this reason I'm asking you that if you can give me the code for this. What I'm doing here is developing a list of sites which are using what kind of doc type and char-set (basically getting which sites are using utf-8 so that theoretically they are using other language than english).

Comment: The problem is that your problem most probably doesn't lie in this piece of code, but somewhere else. In order to find that, you need to debug your code.

Comment: Ok. Finally I solved the problem.It was actually with the server, not my code. Server adding some extra slashes with the data so  it is not getting the exact data. Now its ok. Thanks anyway for giving your time.